# How can I resolve "no token provided" message with React?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, token, spotify

(New at React) I'm having some problems with spotify api's authorization part in my web app. The token does not refresh, and an `401 error` is displayed.

The objective is to show some artists info. When you click on the artist's  name, the application asks you to login, and then redirects you to a page that contains the info. But the token only works for a period of time, when it expires, it should be asking the user to login again

Callback.js:

```
    componentDidMount () {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        let expires = localStorage.getItem('expires')

    if (!token || (expires && new Date().getTime() > new Date(expires).getTime())) {

      window.location.replace(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=c2f9f5a873274c43a6eadd0076111423&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=${this.state.id}`)
    }

    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/${this.state.id}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).then((json) => {
      this.setState({
        artist: json
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Details.js

```
if (!token || (expires && new Date().getTime() > new Date(expires).getTime())) {

  window.location.replace(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=c2f9f5a873274c43a6eadd0076111423&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=${this.state.id}`)
}

fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/${this.state.id}`, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  }
}).then((response) => {
  return response.json()
}).then((json) => {
  this.setState({
    artist: json
  })
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

The error is this one:

> "error": { "status": 401, "message": "No token provided" }

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Anyone should be able to copy your code and run it for themselves without any errors. For example `componentDidMount:` is incorrect JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I also suggest you read the Spotify API documentation.

Comment: Can you log the value of `token` right before you make the `fetch` call?

Comment: @HenryWoody I just did. It shows the same token used to login the first time I tested

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, I was showing the code part. I just fixed it.